# Ember create object

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to create a new record in ember. In the past I used to manually create each of the model's fields on the object controller, but that really seems superfluous. With the code [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XSxYM/2/), as I start typing information into the text boxes, I get an error

```
Assertion failed: Cannot delegate set('name', t) to the 'content' property of object proxy <App.StockNewController:ember258>: its 'content' is undefined
```

Comment: the code your are talking about is missing in your jsfiddle

Comment: bleak it didn't save. @intuitivepixel its now fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what you are missing are some variables defined in your `App.StockNewController`.
Because when the bindings defined in your templates kick in and there are no such properties defined on your backing controller you get the error. I've changed it a bit and now the error is gone.

```
App.StockNewController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  name: '',
  code: '',
  description: ''
});
```

See here a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/olohov/2/edit).

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: That approach seems superfluous to me. I have 20+ attributes currently. In the future some attributes will be dynamic as well, so hard-coding isn't the way forward. Is there not a way I can inherit the fields from the model object? I assumed that the naming of the controller should tell ember that the controller links to that model and therefore is clever enough to manage the fields.

Comment: simply by defining a model and a controller does not link them the way you are expecting, to much *magic*

Comment: Thats a pity. So the solution is then to define all fields in the model *and* in the objectcontroller. Seems clumsy.

Comment: you can also define a property on your controller which is the type of your model and then in your template reference them doing {{myRecord.name}} etc.

Comment: I'll research that some more. It sounds like the best option

Answer (score 0):

The reason is your StockNewController extends Ember.ObjectController, which extends Ember.ObjectProxy.

Ember.ObjectProxy will delegate all of it’s unknown properties to the content object, with one exception.
If we try to set a new property on a proxy while it’s content is undefined, we will get an exception.

Here you try to set the name property on the ObjectController, when it's content is undefined.

The simple solution will be to set the content before you set any other property. This can be done in the model hook itself.

```
App.StockNewRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Stock.create();
  } 
});
```

For simplicity, I've updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XSxYM/5/) with a plain Ember.Object for the model.

You can get detailed info about ObjectProxy [here](http://darthdeus.github.io/blog/2013/01/27/controller-objectcontroller-and-objectproxy/)

Comment: Essentially same approach as @intuitivepixel's solution. Doesn't solve the problem of having to define fields in both the model and the controller.